# Internal Error when sending Push Notification

Tags: parse-platform

Since 2 weeks ago, I get an Internal Error when I want to send a Push Notification to users from my app using Parse.

Here is the error screen:

[image: Push Notifications: Internal Error]

The app is for iOS and Android.

Comment: Is your issue resolved?